# Multiplication always results in 0 despite using the float data type

Tags: c, arithmetic-expressions

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float income;
    printf("enter your annual income here:");
    scanf("%f", &income);
    if (income < 250000)
    {
        printf("no income tax"); /* code */
    }
    else if (income >= 250000 && income < 500000)
    {
        printf("your income tax will be:%f", 5 / 100 * income);
    }
    else if (income >= 500000 && income < 1000000)
    {
        printf("your income tax will be:%f", 20 / 100 * income);
    }
    else if (income >= 1000000)
    {
        printf("your income tax will be:%f", 30 / 100 * income);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code, entering values more than 250000, I still get 0 as my tax output, even though I have used the `float` data type.

Comment: `5 / 100` is always 0 - you should read up on integer division

Comment: Try, for example: `printf("Value: %f\n", (25.0 / 100) * income);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression `5 / 100 * income`, the multiplication operator `*` and division operator `/` have equal precedence and group from left to right.  So it parses as `(5 / 100) * income`

The subexpression `5 / 100` has integer arguments to the division operator, so the result is truncated to an integer.  This results in 0.

If you change either operand (or both) to a floating point constant, i.e. `5.0 / 100`, `5 / 100.0`, or `5.0 / 100.0`, then floating point division will occur and you'll get the expected result.

`20 / 100` and `30 / 100` have the same problem, so change those to `20.0 / 100` and `30.0 / 100` respectively.

Or get rid of the division entirely and use the constants `0.05`, `0.2`, and `0.3`.

Comment: Strictly, using `5.0 / 100` will produce a `double` result (as `5.0` is a `double` constant).  You could use `5.0f / 100` to produce a `float`, or you can decide not to fuss about it as the argument to `printf()` will be converted to a `double` anyway because of the ellipsis in the variadic template for `printf()`.

Comment: Suggestion: refer to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion). It's essential to the problem that the expression is evaluated from left to right, and that the conversion to a floating point type doesn't happen until it's too late.